# C# Ajax can't get data from controller response

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I have a question about ajax.
I have URL : http://localhost:57295/api/Formgetstatus/id=admin&password=test123!&orderNo=000016-150000012

When i click this URL then browser display information responsed :

```
<FormGetStatusRespond xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/FormService.RestApi">
<ResultInfo>
<ErrorInfo i:nil="true"/>
<ErrorType>None</ErrorType>
<Status>Ok</Status>
</ResultInfo>
<Status>OK</Status>
<StatusCode>1</StatusCode>
</FormGetStatusRespond>
```

And this is controller response:

```
public FormGetStatusRespond GetStatus(string id, string password, string orderNo)
        {
            var respond = new FormGetStatusRespond();
            var resultInfor = new ResultInfo();
            var errorInfor = new ErrorInfo();

            if(!this.AuthenticateForUser(id, password))
            {
                // Result Infor
                resultInfor.Status = WebApiStatus.Error;
                resultInfor.ErrorType = WebApiErrorType.AuthenticationError;

                // Error Infor
                errorInfor.Messsage = "abc";

                resultInfor.ErrorInfo = errorInfor;

                respond.ResultInfo = resultInfor;

                return respond;
            }

            var orderDal = new OrderRepository();
            var orderModel = orderDal.FindByOrderNo(orderNo);

            if(orderModel != null)
            {
                // Result Infor
                resultInfor.Status = WebApiStatus.Ok;
                resultInfor.ErrorType = WebApiErrorType.None;
                respond.ResultInfo = resultInfor;
                respond.Status = this.GetOrderStatus(orderModel.OrderStatus);
                respond.StatusCode = ((int)orderModel.OrderStatus).ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                // Result Infor
                resultInfor.Status = WebApiStatus.Error;
                resultInfor.ErrorType = WebApiErrorType.ApplicationError;

                // Error Infor
                errorInfor.Messsage = "abc：" + orderNo + "abc";

                resultInfor.ErrorInfo = errorInfor;

                respond.ResultInfo = resultInfor;

                return respond;
            }

            return respond;
        }
```

I use ajax to get data XML :

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "http://localhost:57295/api/Formgetstatus/id=admin&password=test123!&orderNo=000016-150000012",
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: function (data) {
          alert('b');
        },
        error: function (error) {
          alert('a');
        }
      });
```

I don't know why i can't get data from ajax. Please help me! Thanks everyone!

Comment: What is the result?  Are you seeing alert "a" or "b"?

If it's b, then what's in the "data" object?
Instead of doing alert('b') try 
alert(JSON.stringify(data))

same for the error object.  Let us see what you're getting.

Comment: Use the F12 tool in your browser to see the actual response.  Does it include a <html> tag at the top, or is it pure xml as you're hoping?

Comment: when I use ajax, it is error. I hope result response in data object is xml data.

Comment: Hi GeekyMonkey! This is alert(JSON.stringify(error)) :
{
 "readyState":0,
 "responseText":"",
 "responseXML":null,
 "status":0,
 "statusText":"error"
}

Comment: Ok. so the problem is on the server side.  Can you post the source code for the FormGetStatusRespond class?  What is it's base class?

Comment: this is class FormGetStatusResponse:
public class FormGetStatusRespond
 {
  public string StatusCode { get; set; }
  
  public string Status { get; set; }

  public ResultInfo ResultInfo { get; set; }
 }

Comment: Hi GeekyMonkey! I try on IE is success, on Chrome is not. Why??? I think problem is browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value from your controller action should be something that derives from ActionResult.  Try converting your object to an xml string then returning

```
return this.Content(xmlString, "text/xml");
```

so the response type is set to xml